# Images and assets not working in my production server on rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I switched my server to production and i cannot get any of my images to load. It all works fine on development mode but when i switched to production it all stopped working i have enabled server_static_assets and still yet nothing works. Any help towards doing this

Comment: even image_tag is not working

Comment: i can see this in my server log `cache: [GET /assets/icon_thumb.png] stale, valid, store`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few problems that you might be having:

1 - Your production configuration may not be correct.  This is particularly likely if you started out with an early 3.1 release candidate, and have been updating along the way.  The suggested options for production.rb changed quite a bit between rc4 and the 3.1.0 release.

Make sure that your production.rb settings include:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

2 - You may have forgotten to precompile your assets

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

3 - You may have forgotten to restart your web server to pick up the changes in production.rb.

Comment: yea thanks i also had to run rake rails:update to get it all up to

Answer (score 1):

Remember to run `rake assets:precompile` in your production environment.

If you need are deploying with [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), you can use this recipe:

```
before "deploy:symlink", "assets:precompile"

namespace :assets do
  desc "Compile assets"
  task :precompile, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} assets:precompile"
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also add `load 'deploy/assets'` to your deploy.rb

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading to Rails 4 or are currently using it on production, and are loading images from css, then:

instead of

```
background-image: url('some_image.jpg');
```

do

```
background-image: image-url('some_image.jpg');
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass for reference

Comment: This is unrealistic when using js libraries.