# Rails 4 asset precompile image error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, passenger, apache2.2

I have an application that is being upgraded from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and everything is working fine in development on a Windows 7 box.  However, when I try to test production on a CentOS 5.10 virtual machine the images are broken.  Firefox displays, "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors" and Chrome just appears blank.  When I use curl I get the following information:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 20:36:44 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
>   Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
>   ETag: "6fda96e78f0677973258d551e4c1a95e"
>   X-Request-Id: 6ae8054b-8756-4ab1-906f-10ce13da31ed
>   X-Runtime: 0.004431
>   X-Sendfile: /home/foo/app/assets/images/loading.gif
>   X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.41
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Jun 2014 20:38:10 GMT
>   Status: 200 OK
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: image/gif

As you can see I am using Phusion Passenger 4.0.41 on Apache 2.2.3.  CentOS is version 5.10.  I also double checked that mod_xsendfile was indeed installed, and it was.

I've tried everything that they suggested [on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1822) with no success.

My logs just say `Started GET "asset-files/loading.gif for 10.0.0.187 at 2014-06-03 -0600` (Note the assets was changed to asset-files due to a conflicting model named asset from the Rails 2 days).

I did precompile my assets also.  As well as delete the cache.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a good StackOverflow post on it, which can be found on [Images and assets not working in my production server on rails 3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340635/images-and-assets-not-working-in-my-production-server-on-rails-3-1-0).

Basically, I had to add the following two lines to my config/enviornments/production.rb file:

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Then I compiled the assets again and restarted the application and it now appears to be working.